# How are Lua Function Parameters handed over?

Tags: function, class, parameters, lua

I'm using lua for a project and now I want to use some functions of another class in another file. But it seems not working right for me. The first parameter is not getting handed over but I dont know why.

File index.lsp:

```
dbc = dofile("/home/mako/www/.lua/DBC.lua")
dbc.connectDevice(name, id, ptid)
```

DBC.lua:

```
function DBC:connectDevice(name, id, ptid)
    trace(name)
    trace(id)
    trace(ptid)
end
```

on the trace I get printed:

```
1
72893789(ptid)
nil
```

instead of

```
ESP
1
72893789
```

aswell when I change the order of the parameters it is like an offset as seen next

index.lsp:

```
dbc.connectDevice(id, name, ptid)
```

DBC.lua

```
function DBC:connectDevice(id, name, ptid)
    trace(name)
    trace(id)
    trace(ptid)
end
```

on the trace I get printed:

```
ESP
72893789(ptid)
nil
```

instead of

```
1
ESP
72893789
```

Could somebody maybe explain it to me what I have to do or am I making any mistake?

Comment: Ultimately, it depends on the intent of the DBC.lua author. Presumably, it's body returns an object meant to be passed back as the `self` parameter for connectDevice. This is explained in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in Lua, the syntax `function DBC:connectDevice(name, id, ptid) ... end` is just shorthand for the following code:

```
function DBC.connectDevice(self, name, id, ptid)
  ...
end
```

Note the implicit `self` parameter as the first function argument. This means that when you call the function, you must pass the object as the first argument, like this:

```
DBC.connectDevice(DBC, name, id, ptid)
```

Or, you can use the colon syntax again, to pass the object implicitly:

```
DBC:connectDevice(name, id, ptid)
```

Comment: You mean `DBC.connectDevice(dbc, name, id, ptid)` and `dbc:connectDevice(name, id, ptid)`, I think.

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes, that's correct. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
dbc.connectDevice(name, id, ptid)
function DBC:connectDevice(name, id, ptid)
```

The function is defined as a method, but is called as a function; you probably need to use `dbc:connectDevice(name, id, ptid)` instead.

Since you defined the function as a method, it expect implicit `self` parameter to be passed, and when you call it as a function, it takes the first parameter to be that implicit parameter and shifts all the other parameters, which is what you see.

This [section in PiL](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) may be useful.